# How do I play Tetris in Emacs?

Tags: games

How do I play Tetris inside Emacs?

I've done this a long time ago but I can't remember the commands.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by typing `M-x tetris`.

Comment: Note that [Fedora doesn't ship tetris.el](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=224627) due to trademark questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it on the menu bar (`Tools -> Games -> Tetris`).